# mongodb find objects on basis of pair of keys both matching

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have these JSON Objects

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc1", description: "product 1", qty: 300 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "abc2", description: "product 2", qty: 200 }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "xyz1", description: "product 3", qty: 250 }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "VWZ1", description: "product 4", qty: 300 }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "VWZ2", description: "product 5", qty: 180 }
```

And i want to find the objects for which item is abc2 and qty is 200 ... & object for which item is vwz2 and its qty is 100.

Can it be possible in one single mongo query ?

```
db.collection.find({"item":"abc2","qty":200})
```

Would only return 1, & how to pass another set i have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) which is as defined is another set of conditions that can match:

```js
db.collection.find({ 
    "$or": [
        {"item":"abc2","qty":200},
        {"item":"VWZ2","qty":100}
    ]
})
```

So it is basically a "list" of conditions to query on. Noting that that "qty" does not match your sample but `180` would match.